# Function that is the sum of all of its derivatives

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have just started learning about differential equations, as a result I started to think about this question but couldn't get anywhere. So I googled and wasn't able to find any particularly helpful results. I am more interested in the reason or method rather than the actual answer. Also I do not know if there even is a solution to this but if there isn't I am just as interested to hear why not.

Is there a solution to the differential equation:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^{(n)}(x)$$

Comment: Assume everything works well, and differentiate the equation. Looking sharply, you will see a first order ODE emerging.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am afraid you have lost me. This is what confuses me: How can differentiating an infinite order ODE produce a first order ODE? Thanks.

Comment: If you differentiate the equation, and assume that everything behaves nicely, what equation do you obtain?

Comment: @DanielFischer $f'(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty f^{(n)}(x)$ ?

Comment: Right. And now look, how does that right hand side differ from the original right hand side?

Comment: @DanielFischer By $f'(x)$. Which gives $f'(x)=f(x)-f'(x)$ therefore $f(x)=2 f'(x)$. Ah Ok got it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: And don't forget the boring solution (for all homogeneous linear differential equations):  $0$.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

$f(x)=\exp(\frac{1}{2}x)$ is such a function, since $f^{(n)}=2^{-n} f(x)$, you have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}f(x)=(2-1)f(x)=f(x)$$

This is the only function (up to a constant prefactor) for which $\sum_{n}f^{(n)}$ and its derivatives converge uniformly (on compacta), as $$f'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^{(n+1)}=f-f'$$ follows from this assumption. But this is the same as $f-2 f'=0$, of which the only (real) solutions are $f(x)= C \exp{\frac{x}{2}}$ for some $C \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Being little pedantic: the constant zero function would work too.

Comment: @DBS this is covered by $C=0$.

Comment: Oops you are right. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Does it remain to determine whether there are some more solutions where the convergence of the series is (point-wise but) __not__ uniform, then?

Comment: It remains to be determined :)

Comment: We know that if a limit exists, it must be in the family of functions, but how do we check that the sum converges?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD do you mean in the case of the functions given? They converge (uniformly on compacta) because of the geometric series: if $K$ is compact $\|f-\sum_n^Nf^{(n)}\|_K=\|(1-\sum_n^N2^{-n})f\|_K=(1-\sum_n^N2^{-n})\|f\|_K$ which converges to zero.

Answer (score 22):

Differentiate both sides to get $f'(x)=f''(x)+f^{(3)}(x)+...$

So the starting equation becomes $f(x)=f'(x)+f'(x)\Rightarrow f(x)=2f'(x)$

Multiply now both sides by $e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$ and this becomes
$$[e^{-\frac{x}{2}}f(x)]'=0$$
So $f(x)=ce^{\frac{x}{2}}$
Done.

Answer (score 4):

the question means:
$$y-y'-y''-y'''-......y^n=0$$
the differential equation is homogeneous and the characteristics equation is
$$1-r-r^2-r^3-.......r^n=0$$
$$r(1+r+r^2+r^3+....)=1$$
by using the geometric series (r<1)
$$\frac{r}{1-r}=1$$
$$r=1-r$$
$$r=\frac{1}{2}$$ 
so the function is
$$y=Ce^{\frac{x}{2}}$$